# Shifted symbol cipher

Tags: lateral-thinking, cipher

This is a cool cipher I determined. It involves lateral thinking, so try it out. The answer is a English plaintext, with the following being the cipher text... Try to decrypt it... or decipher it, you get what I mean.

```
ɖɸɔɱʂβʉθ ɸʀ t͡ʃʃɱʍʝɾɦ χɪf ŋɱʎɪə djtiis
```

Non-IPA Ciphertext: DPOMSBUT PR TSMWJRH XIf NMYIE djtiis (Caps don't matter)

Hint:

> Some symbols are IPA phonetic vowels, others are not.
>  The date this was posted is important... 11/14/14.
>  Date shift cipher...
>  Shift right...
>  Remember a date shift cipher shifts the letters by a date. 
>  Don't include slashes...
>  The answer is a short compliment.

Small riddle:

My letters are multi-meaning
Frequencies are off the charts.
Symbols are a nuisance
Think outside the box...

What you want is here,
but you can achieve somewhere else...

Comment: 'Symobls' and 'nusiance' rather than 'symbols' and 'nuisance' - is this a hint or just a typo?

Comment: I shifted them all down by (11+14+14) but got bupkis.

Comment: @randal'thor I thought that was a clue :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it to be:

> congrats on solving the mixed cipher

However, I actually got different letters for the fourth and sixth letters.

> Just using the date cipher as you mentioned:
> `DPOMSBUT PR TSMWJRH XIf NMYIE djtiis`
> `11141411 14 1411141 411 14141 114141`
> `CONIRXTS ON SOLVING THe MIXED cipher`
> Here, for example, D going 1 letter back is C (C ← D), and R going 4 letters back is N (N ← O ← P ← Q ← R).

Comment: Good! Those wrong letters were a red herring.

Comment: Well spotted @Michael!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot quite decipher the text, but the last 3 words seem to me like

> with number digits

Comment: Sadly it is wrong. The symbols are just IPA phonetic vowels, and the date this was posted, 11/14/14 is important.

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 - You should mention the date explicitly in your hints, because it depends on the timezone. When I hover over 'asked 2 days ago' it says the question was posted just after midnight on 11/15/14!

Comment: @randal'thor Actually for me, the fifteenth month doesn't have 11 days! So, yeah, it is indeed essential to post these hints explicitly, including, if necessary, the intended date format :)

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 For future reference, because we are in different timezones the date I see is 11/15/14.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so here's what I've got so far:

> "Some symbols are IPA phonetic vowels, others are not" - but they are all IPA phonetic symbols! Taking the IPA code for each symbol, your message becomes: 
>  106, 126, 306, 115, 136, 127, 318, 130 
>  126, 123 
>  103, 134, 115, 169, 139, 124, 147 
>  142, 319, 128 
>  119, 115, 157, 319, 322 
>  104, 153, 103, 301, 301, 132

As for the date...

> following the hint on your user profile, I'd like to try shifting all these numbers by something. But 11+14+14 seems too big. Maybe 11-14+14 or 14-11+14?

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Could it be vowels versus consonants?

Comment: @AE - They're almost all consonants; I think the vowels are the big numbers, so only six of them.

Comment: @AE just look for a IPA phonetic vowel keyboard, find what letter the symbol is, and replace accordingly.

Comment: @randal'thor The date is correct, but the top half isn't.

Comment: @randal'thor Someone letters are "encoded" as IPA phonetic symbols, but others aren't.

Comment: Helped to remove the "frequency" with respect to http://ipa.typeit.org/full/. Uppercase are IPA, lowercase are not. What could we do with this?

DPOMSBUT PR TSMWJRH XIf NMYIE djtiis

Comment: @nexolute - I don't understand what you've done here. Symbols like 'f' and 'i' *are* IPA characters even if they're also letters of the Latin alphabet. *All* the characters in the ciphertext are in the IPA.

Comment: @randal'thor All characters are IPA, but not all are ASCII. So if they are ASCII, I will just treat them as not IPA. Also, I interprete "frequency are off the chart" as removing their tonal meaning.